# I want to use a big product symbol I have a problem

Tags: symbols

```
\documentclass[14pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
$$P:=\prod_{\sigma\in \textnormal{Gal}(L/K)}\big(X-\sigma(b)\big)\in A[X],$$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the  problem?

Comment: Add `\usepackage{fixcmex}`. By the way, you don't need to load `amstext` and for “Gal” you should use `\operatorname{Gal}`. Don't use `$$`, see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Comment: @ Bernard the symbol pi is small